# GITLAB branch not inheriting Group variables

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ee

I created 4 group variables in GITLAB. However, when I go into the master branch CI/CD settings and go to variables I don't see the group variables. From my understanding, the branch is suppose to inherit those global variables.  Does anyone know what I have done wrong? Is there a setting I missed when creating those global variables?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on `Group CI/CD variables` [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#group-cicd-variables), the variables in *subgroups* are recursively inherited. I confirm this, we use this capacity at work.

Please, check that you are defining your variables in a *subgroup* and not in the *major/organization group*.

In addition, please verify that you are checking the variables in the supposed site. I believe that, in your situation, you are defining the variables in Gitlab itself and not in `gitlab-ci.yml`. Therefore, those variables should not be dependent on any branch, but on the Gitlab (sub)group and repository - independently from the branch.